# Pythagoras's theorem as a special case of the law of cosines

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I heard that the Pythagorean theorem is a special case of the more general theorem relating the lengths of sides in any triangle, the law of cosines?

Comment: What is your Question?

Comment: Yes. Pythagoras Theorem can be seen as a very particular case of the cosines law, though historically it is not so.

Comment: @fcpatidar11 welcome to math.stackexchange! You might want to have a look at the short intro to the site mechanics, to get the hang of how things work around here :)

Answer (score 6):

The **law of cosines** is:
$$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 \;-\; 2\!\cdot\!a\!\cdot\!b\!\cdot\!\cos\theta$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between the sides $a$ and $b$.
Now, when this angle is a *right angle* ($90^\circ$, or $\frac{\pi}{2}$), its cosine is $0$, so the entire last term is multiplied by $0$ and vanishes, leaving only the usual **Pythagorean Theorem** for the *right triangle* with legs $a$ and $b$ and the hypotenuse $c$:
$$c^2 = a^2 + b^2$$
Simple as that.

Answer (score 5):

Yup: it states that
$$
a=\sqrt{b^2+c^2-2bc\cos\alpha}
$$
in standard trigonometric notation (where $a,b,c$ are the sides of the triangle, and $\alpha$ is the angle which is opposite to $a$).

A simple proof can be given with vector calculus: being $\vec{a}=\vec{b}-\vec{c}$, squaring this relation you obtain:
$$
\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a}\equiv a^2 = b^2 + c^2 - 2 \vec{b}\cdot \vec{c}
$$ 
which is the formula above substituting the definition of scalar product!

Comment: how do you prove $a.b=|a||b|\cos\theta$?.You need law of cosine to do that!.This is circular reasoning

Comment: @Cloud JR actually that is my definition of scalar product